# Chrome Canary - no styles

Tags: css, google-chrome

I've just downloaded Chrome's beta browser and the css appears to be switched [off](http://i1200.photobucket.com/albums/bb328/tobeeornot/Chrome.jpg). Cannot see anything in the settings or dev tools to change it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chrome you have it in the settings section

`Via the gear icon, choose the "CSS" tab > "Disable All Styles"`